# C# Secure Video Encryption

Tags: c#, video, encryption, permissions, directory

I have set of videos which I want my wpf application to access and play it. User should not have access the file directly or copy it.

I tried few ideas such as 
- Password protecting the folder
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-windows-using-C-Concepts-on

- Folder permissions.
  But its not working well.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some samples of what you tried and what is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

- if you have a server then create an api and only send back a stream, setup permissions and add them in your code
- if you have a network share then use permission and use WindowsIdentity.Impersonate
- if it must be local then you will need to store it encrypted and then decrypt it.

be aware streams can be captured and saved

Comment: Thanks, i have another question but didnt get proper answer. Another idea is i can have the video files inside a folder with admin access. When user login he cannot access to folder. When he runs the application it accesses the folder using admin logins. How to access a local folder using logins.

Comment: same as the network share then, have the access wrapped with an windows.impersonate The only down side to this is that it easy to decompile a .net application and extract the username and password. an easy route is often plagued with problems

Comment: Smith Thanks, I would try that.